# Get all the employees who are enrolled in all the three plans in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am working on three SQL table and try to get all the employees who are enrolled in all the three plans as follows

Table: **Employee**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ FirstName ║ LastName  ║ Birthdate ║ HomeState ║ Gender ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║          1 ║ John      ║ Doe       ║ 1/1/1978  ║ FL        ║ M      ║
║          2 ║ Jane      ║ Eyre      ║ 4/7/1985  ║ AL        ║ F      ║
║          3 ║ Alexander ║ Hamilton  ║ 6/4/1960  ║ NY        ║ M      ║
║          4 ║ Chris     ║ Smith     ║ 12/5/1990 ║ CA        ║ M      ║
║          5 ║ Emily     ║ Dickinson ║ 3/5/1945  ║ VT        ║ F      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

Table: **Plan**:

```
╔════════╦══════════╦════════════════╗
║ PlanID ║ PlanType ║    PlanName    ║
╠════════╬══════════╬════════════════╣
║      1 ║ Medical  ║ Medical Plan 1 ║
║      2 ║  Dental  ║ Dental Plan 1  ║
║      3 ║ Vision   ║ Vision Plan 1  ║
║      4 ║ Medical  ║ Medical Plan 2 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩════════════════╝
```

Table: **PlanEnrollment**

```
╔══════════════╦════════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ EnrollmentID ║ EmployeeID ║ PlanID ║ EnrollmentStartDate ║ ErollmentEndDate ║
╠══════════════╬════════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║            1 ║          1 ║      1 ║ 1/1/2015            ║ 3/1/2015         ║
║            2 ║          1 ║      2 ║ 1/1/2014            ║ NULL             ║
║            3 ║          2 ║      1 ║ 6/1/2013            ║ 5/1/2015         ║
║            4 ║          3 ║      4 ║ 2/1/2013            ║ NULL             ║
║            5 ║          4 ║      2 ║ 5/3/2015            ║ 7/1/2015         ║
║            6 ║          1 ║      4 ║ 3/2/2015            ║ NULL             ║
╚══════════════╩════════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

From the above tables I'm trying to retrieve first and last names of all employees who are currently enrolled in all three Medical,Dental and Vision plans.

How to do this?

Comment: Just to make the example more confusing, you have 2 different medical plans?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.  I'm still not a SQL expert though.  I could be missing something in the quer.

```
SELECT * FROM `PlanEnrollment`,`Employee` 
WHERE COUNT(`PlanEnrollment`.`EmployeeID`) = 3
AND `PlanEnrollment`.`PlanID` != 4
GROUP BY `PlanEnrollment`.`EmployeeID`
JOIN `Employee` ON `PlanEnrollment`.`EmployeeID` = `Employee`.`EmployeeID`
```

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax, SQL Server uses [] around keywords, but those shouldn't be necessary here, and the join part should be in from clause

Comment: and that count isn't something that even works in SQL Server, you need to use having

Comment: Yes it's mysql.  SQL syntax in general is close across products.  I don't use MS SQL Server, but I see a count function on their kb.  If not, there has to be an equivalent function.

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
SELECT e.firstname, 
       e.lastname
FROM Employee e 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT PlanID
                  FROM Plan
                  WHERE PlanType IN ('Medical', 'Dental', 'Vision')
                  EXCEPT 
                  SELECT PlanID
                  FROM PlanEnrollment pe
                  WHERE pe.EmployeeID= e.EmployeeID)
```

In a nutshell, for each employee, this will find the list of plan ids you are interested in, subtract the plans that employee is enrolled in. If the subtraction is null, that means the that the employee is enrolled in all plans and the NOT EXISTS will return this employee for you.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/375247)**</kbd>

How it works:

1. Get all employee plans that are current valid
2. Left Join To Plan table 3 times (for Vision, Dental, Medical)
3. Sum it up
4. Select those employee who has 3
5. Join to `Employee` table and get personal data

Query:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT EmployeeId, 
    [dental] = SUM(IIF(p.PlanId IS NULL,0, 1)),
    [vision] = SUM(IIF(p2.PlanId IS NULL,0, 1)),
    [medical] = SUM(IIF(p3.PlanId IS NULL,0, 1))
  FROM #PlanEnrollment pe
  LEFT JOIN #Plan p
    ON pe.PlanId = p.PlanID
    AND p.PlanType LIKE 'Dental'
  LEFT JOIN #Plan p2
    ON pe.PlanId = p2.PlanID
    AND p2.PlanType LIKE 'Vision'
  LEFT JOIN #Plan p3
    ON pe.PlanId = p3.PlanID
   AND p3.PlanType LIKE 'Medical'
  WHERE GETDATE() >= EnrollmentStartDate 
    AND GETDATE() <= ISNULL(ErollmentEndDate, '2099-01-01')
  GROUP BY EmployeeId
)
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName
FROM cte c
JOIN  #Employee e 
  ON c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeId
WHERE [dental] > 0 AND [vision] > 0 AND [medical] > 0;
```

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee(
  EmployeeID INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,FirstName  VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL
  ,LastName   VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL
  ,Birthdate  DATE  NOT NULL
  ,HomeState  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Gender     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Birthdate,HomeState,Gender) VALUES (1,'John','Doe','1/1/1978','FL','M');
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Birthdate,HomeState,Gender) VALUES (2,'Jane','Eyre','4/7/1985','AL','F');
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Birthdate,HomeState,Gender) VALUES (3,'Alexander','Hamilton','6/4/1960','NY','M');
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Birthdate,HomeState,Gender) VALUES (4,'Chris','Smith','12/5/1990','CA','M');
INSERT INTO #Employee(EmployeeID,FirstName,LastName,Birthdate,HomeState,Gender) VALUES (5,'Emily','Dickinson','3/5/1945','VT','F');


CREATE TABLE #Plan(
  PlanID   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PlanType VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
  ,PlanName VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #Plan(PlanID,PlanType,PlanName) VALUES (1,'Medical','Medical Plan 1');
INSERT INTO #Plan(PlanID,PlanType,PlanName) VALUES (2,'Dental','Dental Plan 1');
INSERT INTO #Plan(PlanID,PlanType,PlanName) VALUES (3,'Vision','Vision Plan 1');
INSERT INTO #Plan(PlanID,PlanType,PlanName) VALUES (4,'Medical','Medical Plan 2');


CREATE TABLE #PlanEnrollment(
   EnrollmentID        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,EmployeeID          INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,PlanID              INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,EnrollmentStartDate DATE   NULL
  ,ErollmentEndDate    DATE  NULL
);
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (1,1,1,'1/1/2015','3/1/2015');
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (2,1,2,'1/1/2014',NULL);
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (3,2,1,'6/1/2013','5/1/2015');
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (4,3,4,'2/1/2013',NULL);
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (5,4,2,'5/3/2015','7/1/2015');
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (6,1,4,'3/2/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #PlanEnrollment(EnrollmentID,EmployeeID,PlanID,EnrollmentStartDate,ErollmentEndDate) VALUES (8,1,3,'3/2/2015',NULL);
```

Comment: @Dev I updated my answer, now employee can has multiple medical,dental, vision plans

Answer (score 0):

This query will work:

```
SELECT em.[First Name] as EmployeeFirstName, em.[Last Name] as EmployeeLastName
FROM
(
    SELECT pe.EmployeeID, count(DISTINCT p.PlanType) as DistinctPlanTypeCount
    FROM
        PlanEnrollment pe
        JOIN [Plan] p on pe.PlanID = p.PlanID
    WHERE
        pe.EnrollmentStartDate <= GETDATE() and
        (pe.EnrollmentEndDate is NULL or pe.EnrollmentEndDate > GETDATE())
    GROUP BY pe.EmployeeID
) Q1
JOIN Employee em ON Q1.EmployeeID = em.EmployeeID
WHERE Q1.DistinctPlanTypeCount = (SELECT count(DISTINCT PlanType) FROM [Plan])
```

The inner query returns

```
╔════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ EmployeeID ║ DistinctPlanTypeCount ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║          1 ║                     2 ║
║          3 ║                     1 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

The outer query gets the Employee columns and filters by distinct PlanType count.

The result is an empty set

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ EmployeeFirstName ║ EmployeeLastName ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep is simple.
The first FROM PlanEnrollment filter all the employees that have a medical plan: 
`WHERE p1.PlanID in (1,4)` -- one of the medical plans
The first join filters this result set to the employees that have Dental
The second join filters this result set to the employees that have Vision

The third join just gets a reference back to the employees so you can list their names.  `SELECT e.*`

```
SELECT e.*
FROM PlanEnrollemnt p1
JOIN PlanEnrollment p2 on p1.EmployeeID = p2.EmployeeId and PlanId = 2 --Dental
JOIN PlanEnrollment p3 on p1.EmployeeID = p3.EmployeeId and PlanId = 3 -- Vison
JOIN Employee e = p1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE p1.PlanID in (1,4) -- one of the medical plans
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Pivot and it worked. See below.

```
SELECT EmployeeFirstName
    , EmployeeLastName
FROM 
(
    SELECT E.FirstName AS EmployeeFirstName
       , E.LastName AS EmployeeLastName
       , R.EmployeeID
       , P.PlanType
    FROM PlanEnrollment R INNER JOIN [Plan] P
       ON R.PlanID = P.PlanID INNER JOIN Employee E
          ON R.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    WHERE EnrollmentEndDate IS NULL
       AND R.EnrollmentStartDate <= GETDATE()
) SRC PIVOT (COUNT(EmployeeID) FOR PlanType in ([Medical], [Dental], [Vision])) PIVOTTABLE
WHERE Medical > 0
    AND Dental > 0
    AND Vision > 0;
```